# Fast Modulo 511 and 127

Tags: performance, modulo

Is there a way, how to make modulo by 511 (and 127) faster than using "%" operator ?

```
int c = 758 % 511;
int d = 423 % 127;
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709651/is-it-possible-to-rewrite-modulo-2n-1-using-bitwise-and-restricted-operator

Comment: Like this: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivision

Comment: Yes, Mystical's link gives *the* answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do fast modulo by 511 assuming that x is at most 32767.  It's about twice as fast as `x%511`. It does the modulo in five steps: two multiply, two addition, one shift.

```
inline int fast_mod_511(int x) {
    int y = (513*x+64)>>18;
    return x - 511*y;
}
```

Here is the theory at how I arrive at this.  I posted the code I tested this at the end

Let's consider

```
y = x/511 = x/(512-1) = x/1000 * 1/(1-1/512).
```

Let's define z = 512, then

```
y = x/z*1/(1-1/z).
```

Using Taylor expansion

```
y = x/z(1 + 1/z + 1/z^2 + 1/z^3 + ...).
```

Now if we know that x has a limited range we can cut the expansion.  Let's assume x is always less than 2^15=32768.  Then we can write

```
512*512*y = (1+512)*x = 513*x.
```

After looking at the digits which are significant we arrive at

```
y = (513*x+64)>>18 //512^2 = 2^18.
```

**We can divide x/511 (assuming x is less than 32768) in three steps:**

```
multiply,
add,
shift.
```

Here is the code I just to profile this in MSVC2013 64-bit release mode on an Ivy Bridge core.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

inline int fast_mod_511(int x) {
    int y = (513*x+64)>>18;
    return x - 511*y;
}

int main() {
    unsigned int i, x;
    volatile unsigned int r;
    double dtime;

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<32768; j++) {
            r = j%511;
        }     
    }
    dtime =omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time %f\n", dtime);

    dtime = omp_get_wtime();
    for(i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<32768; j++) {
            r = fast_mod_511(j);
        }
    }
    dtime =omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
    printf("time %f\n", dtime);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup table with the solutions pre-stored. If you create an array of a million integers looking up is about twice as fast as actually doing modulo in my C# app.

```
// fill an array
var mod511 = new int[1000000];
for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) mod511[x] = x % 511;
```

and instead of using

```
c = 758 % 511;
```

you use

```
c = mod511[758];
```

This will cost you (possibly a lot of) memory, and will obviously not work if you want to use it for very large numbers also. But it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to repeat those two modulus operations on a large number of data and your CPU supports SIMD (for example Intel's SSE/AVX/AVX2) then you can vectorize the operations, i.e., do the operations on many data in parallel. You can do this by using intrinsics or inline assembly. Yes the solution will be platform specific but maybe that is fine...